# Trying to add class objects to a list, but getting "no overload for method Add takes 3 arguments"

Tags: c#, interface, explicit-interface

I'm trying to solve this problem:

[image: Description of the problem as an image.]

I am working on a homework exercise that is printing info about citizens, and I am stuck on the part where I have to add the citizens to a list of the class `Citizen`. I am getting an error when adding the created objects to a list (`List<Citizen>`) I would want to print in the console:

> No overload for method `Add` takes 3 arguments.

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Citizen> citizens = new List<Citizen>();

        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string country = Console.ReadLine();
        int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        citizens.Add(name,age,country);

        string end = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        while (end!="End")
        {
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            country = Console.ReadLine();
            age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            citizens.Add(name, age, country);
        }
    }
}

public interface IResident
{
    public string Name { get;}
    public string Country { get;}

    public string GetName();
}

public interface IPerson
{
    public string Name { get;}
    public int Age { get;}

    public string GetName();
}

public class Citizen : IPerson, IResident
{
    public Citizen(string name, int age, string country)
    {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Age = age;
       this.Country = country;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public string Country { get; private set; }

    string IPerson.GetName()
    {
        return $"{this.Name}";
    }
    string IResident.GetName()
    {
        return "Mr/Ms/Mrs ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and insert the description of the problem in text format, instead of image?

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a Citizen object and then add that to your list, as `citizens` is of type `List<Citizen>`

So in your code wherever you attempt to add to your list, it must become `citizens.Add(new Citizen(name,age,country));`

The reason for the error message is clear, as there truly is no `.Add()` overload that takes 3 parameters, but that isn't the problem really. Even if there *was* such an overload, you would still get an error due to type mismatch. `List<T>` will strictly enforce whatever `T` you declare for it

Comment: ok so how should i do it then

Comment: @KristiyanArnaudov anywhere in your code that you have `citizens.Add(name, age, country);` must become `citizens.Add(new Citizen(name,age,country));`, that's it. What is happening is 1) you are constructing a new citizen object using parsed user inputs and then 2) you are add that new object into your list

Comment: You're welcome! you as well

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your list to contain citizens, so you need to add a Citizen to your list.
However, your code is currently trying to add a name, age and country to the list, which are strings and integers.

You must therefore create a new Citizen and add it to the list.
You can do this by
`new Citizen(name, age, country);`

So the correct way to implement the add function would be:
`citizens.Add(new Citizen(name,age,country));`

As a related extra, currently, you are calling Add in two places - it may be advisable to only do this in one place to keep things simple. Good luck!